# PL/pgSQL record based on SELECT with CamelCase columns

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm pulling my hair out here. I have the following sample SP - keep in mind I have already declared rec as RECORD;

```
FOR rec IN
   SELECT
     "AclObjects"."ObjectName",
     "AclRoles"."RoleId"
   FROM
     "AclObjects",
     "AclRoles",
     "AclGrantRole"
   WHERE
     "AclObjects"."ObjectRef" = "AclGrantRole"."ObjectRef"
     AND "AclRoles"."RoleId" = "AclGrantRole"."RoleId"
     AND "AclObjects"."ObjectClass" = "inObjectClass"
     AND now() BETWEEN "AclGrantRole"."EffectiveFrom"
                   AND "AclGrantRole"."EffectiveTo"
 LOOP
    "outStatusCode" := 0;
    "outObjectName" := rec."AclRoles"."ObjectName";
    "outObjectName" := rec."AclRoles"."RoleId";
    "outStatusMsg" := NULL;

    return next;
  END LOOP;
```

Notice I'm trying to assign other camel case variables to the record variables. I've tried searching for this but nothing comes up.

Essentially, it's very likely I could have two tables with the same column name that I want to return fully referenced `Table1.ColumnName`, and `Table2.ColumnName`

So:

1) I'm unsure of how RECORD handles fully referenced SELECT values
2) Is it even possible to return them when they are camel case

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `returns table` and remove the whole cursor handling?

Comment: This is only one very small part of this SP - it does a bit of work after and before this point. But thanks for the suggestion, it may help me in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return case sensitive identifier. But second part - rec."AclRoles"."ObjectName" is nonsense - should be rec."ObjectName".

RETURN QUERY or just sql function instead plpgsql is better solution

Comment: Hi Pavel,Thanks for your response. But what happens in the 2 table, same column example I gave - wouldn't that cause ambiguity if you only have to reference by the column name?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't allow ambiguous names.